# Submitting form data to entity1 and entity2_id column is null even when entity1 and entity2 are mapped

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have two entities (Plan and PricingTier) that are set up to be mapped to each other.  The PricingTier is set up to be a oneToMany and the Plan is set up to be a manyToOne. The mapped column is in the Plan entity; the plans database table has a pricing_tier_id column that links the two tables/entities together.

I have a form that creates a new plan.  The form generates properly in the Twig file and when posted the $request->request->getAll(); returns an array of the posted values.  In the array I can see that the pricingTierId has clearly been set to the id of the pricing tier I selected. When I peform the following:

```
$form->bind($request);
$newPlan = $form->getData();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$em->perist($newPlan);
$em->flush();
```

I get a thrown exception saying that pricing_tier_id can not be NULL. I have done a var_dump() to the $newPlan variable and it looks returns an object, including the object of the mapped pricing tier.

Can anyone suggest a solution to why I'd be getting this error?  Relevant code and errors are below.

**PlanController.php**

```
namespace etrak\CustomerServiceBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\Plan;
use etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\PricingTier;
use etrak\CustomerServiceBundle\Form\Type\PlanType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class PlanController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('etrakCustomerServiceBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
    }

    public function addPlanAction(Request $request)
    {
        // Set up a new Plan object
        $plan = new Plan();

        $form = $this->createForm(new PlanType(), $plan);

        // Check to see if the form has been submitted
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->bind($request);
            var_dump($request->request->all()); die();
            // Validate the form
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $newPlan = $form->getData();
//var_dump($newPlan->getPricingTierId()); die();
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($newPlan);
                $em->flush();
            }
        }

        return $this->render('etrakCustomerServiceBundle:Plan:new.html.twig', array("form" => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

**PlanType.php**

```
namespace etrak\CustomerServiceBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class PlanType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\Plan',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));


    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $termsConditionsArray = array("1 Year Contract" => "1 Year Contract", "2 Year Contract" => "2 Year Contract");
        $billingFrequencyArray = array("1" => "Monthly", "6" => "6 Months", "12" => "Yearly");

        // Create the form
        $builder->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Plan Name: ', 'required' => false));
        $builder->add('description', 'text', array('label' => 'Plan Description: '));
        $builder->add('termsConditions', 'choice', array('choices' =>                 $termsConditionsArray, 'label' => 'Terms & Conditions'));
        $builder->add('amount', 'text', array('label' => 'Plan Price: '));
        $builder->add('affinity', 'choice', array('choices' => array('0' => 'Yes', '1' => 'No'), 'label' => 'Affinity? ', 'expanded' => true));
        $builder->add('deactivationFee', 'text', array('label' => "Deactivation Fee: "));
        $builder->add('recurringInMonths', 'choice', array('choices' => $billingFrequencyArray, 'label' => 'Billing Frequency: '));
        $builder->add('pricingTierId', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'etrakOnlineOrderProcessingBundle:pricingTier',
        'property' => 'name',
        'label' => "Select Pricing Tier: "
    ));
        $builder->add('activeStartDate', 'datetime', array('label' => "Effective Start Date: "));
        $builder->add('activeEndDate', 'datetime', array('label' => "Effective End Date: "));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'plan';
    }
}
```

**Plan.php**
    namespace etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Plan
 */
class Plan
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $termsConditions;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $active;

    /**
     * @var decimal
     */
    private $amount;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $affinity;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $deactivationFee;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $gracePeriodDays;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $recurringInMonths;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $pricingTierId;

    /**
     * @var date
     */
    private $activeStartDate;

    /**
     * @var date
     */
    private $activeEndDate;

    /**
     * @var \etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\PricingTier
     */
    private $pricingTier;


    /**
     * Set pricingTier
     *
     * @param \etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\PricingTier $pricingTier
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function setPricingTier(\etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\PricingTier $pricingTier = null)
    {
        $this->pricingTier = $pricingTier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pricingTier
     *
     * @return \etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\PricingTier 
     */
    public function getPricingTier()
    {
        return $this->pricingTier;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set termsConditions
     *
     * @param string $termsConditions
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function setTermsConditions($termsConditions)
    {
        $this->termsConditions = $termsConditions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get termsConditions
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTermsConditions()
    {
        return $this->termsConditions;
    }

    /**
     * Set active
     *
     * @param boolean $active
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function setActive($active)
    {
        $this->active = $active;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get active
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getActive()
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * Set amount
     *
     * @param decimal $amount
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function setAmount($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get amount
     *
     * @return decimal 
     */
    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    /**
     * Set affinity
     *
     * @param boolean $affinity
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function setAffinity($affinity)
    {
        $this->affinity = $affinity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get affinity
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getAffinity()
    {
        return $this->affinity;
    }

    /**
     * Set deactivationFee
     *
     * @param integer $deactivationFee
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function setDeactivationFee($deactivationFee)
    {
        $this->deactivationFee = $deactivationFee;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get deactivationFee
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getDeactivationFee()
    {
        return $this->deactivationFee;
    }

    /**
     * Set gracePeriodDays
     *
     * @param integer $gracePeriodDays
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function setGracePeriodDays($gracePeriodDays)
    {
        $this->gracePeriodDays = $gracePeriodDays;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get gracePeriodDays
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getGracePeriodDays()
    {
        return $this->gracePeriodDays;
    }

    /**
     * Set recurringInMonths
     *
     * @param integer $recurringInMonths
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function setRecurringInMonths($recurringInMonths)
    {
        $this->recurringInMonths = $recurringInMonths;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get recurringInMonths
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getRecurringInMonths()
    {
        return $this->recurringInMonths;
    }

    /**
     * Set pricingTierId
     *
     * @param integer $pricingTierId
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function setPricingTierId($pricingTierId)
    {
        $this->pricingTierId = $pricingTierId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pricingTierId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPricingTierId()
    {
        return $this->pricingTierId;
    }

    /**
     * Set activeStartDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $activeStartDate
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function setActiveStartDate($activeStartDate)
    {
        $this->activeStartDate = $activeStartDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get activeStartDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getActiveStartDate()
    {
        return $this->activeStartDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set activeEndDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $activeEndDate
     * @return Plan
     */
    public function setActiveEndDate($activeEndDate)
    {
        $this->activeEndDate = $activeEndDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get activeEndDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getActiveEndDate()
    {
        return $this->activeEndDate;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        if (!isset($this->affinity)) {
            $this->setAffinity(0);
        }

        if (!isset($this->active)) {
            $this->setActive(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Plan.orm.yml**

```
#etrak/OnlineOrderProcessingBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Entity/Plan.orm.yml
etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\Plan:
  type: entity
  table: plans
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    description:
      type: text
      nullable: true
    termsConditions:
      column: terms_conditions
      type: text
      nullable: true
    active:
      type: boolean
      nullable: true
    amount:
      type: decimal
      nullable: true
      scale: 2
      precision: 5
    affinity:
      type: boolean
      nullable: true
    deactivationFee:
      column: deactivation_fee
      type: decimal
      scale: 2
      precision: 5
      nullable: true
    gracePeriodDays:
      column: grace_period_days
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    recurringInMonths:
      column: recurring_in_months
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    pricingTierId:
      column: pricing_tier_id
      type: integer
    activeStartDate:
      column: active_start_date
      type: date
    activeEndDate:
      column: active_end_date
      type: date
  lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [ prePersist ]
  manyToOne:
    pricingTier:
      targetEntity: PricingTier
      inversedBy: plans
      joinColumn:
        name: pricing_tier_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

**PricingTier.php**

```
namespace etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * PricingTier
 */
class PricingTier
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $productId;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $minimumDevices;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $isAffinity;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $keyname;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $createdBy;

    /**
     * @var datetime
     */
    private $createdOn;

    /**
     * @var datetime
     */
    private $updatedOn;

    /**
     * Set productId
     *
     * @param integer $productId
     * @return PricingTier
     */
    public function setProductId($productId)
    {
        $this->productId = $productId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get productId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getProductId()
    {
        return $this->productId;
    }

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $plans;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->plans = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add plans
     *
     * @param \etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\Plan $plans
     * @return PricingTier
     */
    public function addPlan(\etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\Plan $plans)
    {
        $this->plans[] = $plans;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove plans
     *
     * @param \etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\Plan $plans
     */
    public function removePlan(\etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\Plan $plans)
    {
        $this->plans->removeElement($plans);
    }

    /**
     * Get plans
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getPlans()
    {
        return $this->plans;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return PricingTier
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return PricingTier
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set minimumDevices
     *
     * @param integer $minimumDevices
     * @return PricingTier
     */
    public function setMinimumDevices($minimumDevices)
    {
        $this->minimumDevices = $minimumDevices;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get minimumDevices
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getMinimumDevices()
    {
        return $this->minimumDevices;
    }

    /**
     * Set isAffinity
     *
     * @param boolean $isAffinity
     * @return PricingTier
     */
    public function setIsAffinity($isAffinity)
    {
        $this->isAffinity = $isAffinity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isAffinity
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsAffinity()
    {
        return $this->isAffinity;
    }

    /**
     * Set keyname
     *
     * @param string $keyname
     * @return PricingTier
     */
    public function setKeyname($keyname)
    {
        $this->keyname = $keyname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get keyname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getKeyname()
    {
        return $this->keyname;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdBy
     *
     * @param string $createdBy
     * @return PricingTier
     */
    public function setCreatedBy($createdBy)
    {
        $this->createdBy = $createdBy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdBy
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCreatedBy()
    {
        return $this->createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdOn
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdOn
     * @return PricingTier
     */
    public function setCreatedOn($createdOn)
    {
        $this->createdOn = $createdOn;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdOn
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreatedOn()
    {
        return $this->createdOn;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedOn
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedOn
     * @return PricingTier
     */
    public function setUpdatedOn($updatedOn)
    {
        $this->updatedOn = $updatedOn;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedOn
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedOn()
    {
        return $this->updatedOn;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function onPrePersist()
    {
        if (!isset($this->isAffinity)) {
            $this->setIsAffinity(0);
        }
        $this->setCreatedOn(new \DateTime());
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function onPreUpdate()
    {
        $this->setUpdatedOn(new \DateTime());
    }
}
```

**PricingTier.orm.yml**

```
#etrak/OnlineOrderProcessingBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Entity/PricingTier.orm.yml
etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\PricingTier:
  type: entity
  table: pricing_tiers
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    productId:
      column: product_id
      type: integer
    name:
      type: string
      length: 50
    description:
      type: string
      length: 100
      nullable: true
    minimumDevices:
      column: minimum_devices
      type: integer
    isAffinity:
      column: is_affinity
      type: boolean
    keyname:
      type: string
      length: 55
    createdBy:
      column: created_by
      type: string
      length: 20
    createdOn:
      column: created_on
      type: datetime
    updatedOn:
      column: updated_on
      type: datetime
      nullable: true
  lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [ onPrePersist ]
    preUpdate: [ onPreUpdate ]
  oneToMany:
    plans:
      targetEntity: Plan
      mappedBy: pricingTier
```

That should be all of the files that relate to this.  I didn't include the Twig file because it is simply one line that renders the form that is generated by the createView() magic method in the PlanController.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Plan.orm.yml:

```
pricingTierId:
      column: pricing_tier_id
      type: integer
```

which is the same column name as your many-to-one join.  This is probably a bad practice.  This is not set to nullable: true, and is probably the source of your problem.  Explicitly, you don't need this field.  Also in your form, you are loading the entity class for the pricingTierId, which is not an entity, and I think symfony is quite confused by this.

```
    $builder->add('pricingTierId', 'entity', array(             // add pricingTier
    'class' => 'etrakOnlineOrderProcessingBundle:pricingTier',  // not pricingTierId
    'property' => 'name',
    'label' => "Select Pricing Tier: "
    ));
```

I expect if you delete the offending yaml portion and adjust the form type your problem will go away.

Comment: The ORM mapping for the Plan should be correct..furthermore I don't want that column to be nullable.  The issue is that the form data is POSTing the correct id, but when it is being bound to the $form variable so it can be persisted to the database, it submits the id as null instead of using what was posted.

Comment: In the PlanType.php the builder->add for the pricingTier should be correct as well.  The field name is called pricingTierId, which maps to the pricingTierId variable in the PricingTier class, which maps to the pricingTierId in the PricingTier orm file, which maps to the pricing_tier_id column in the database.  And I'm telling that to auto populate a drop down box using the values from the pricingTier entity, which maps to my pricing_tiers table in the database.

Comment: I can't speak to what _should_ be.  However, what _is_ happening is you have an integer field and a collection field that are mapped the same column in your database, pricing_tier_id, for the plan table.  If you've explained this as you mean, you do _not_ need the field I've mentioned, because it is handled in the many-to-one-join.  If you _do_ need a second copy of this id, it will have to have its own column name, either in the many-to-one section joinColumn name or the princingTierId column.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are referring to now.  When I make those changes, that corrected the issue and it posts to the database.  I wish that the documentation was more clear.  Thanks!

Comment: Please accept answer, so others don't look for alternate solutions.  That's quite a read, and I wouldn't want to waste other's time.  Actually it's quite an interesting problem.  I'm surprised doctrine let you do anything with that situation.